# How to solve conflicting getter definitions for property in jackson without access to source

Tags: java, json, jackson, getter, jackson2

I'm getting this error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Could not write JSON: Conflicting getter definitions for property "oid"
```

The problem is that the class has two similar methods:

`getOID` (deprecated) and `getOid`

But I cannot modify the class as it's just a dependency.

Is there a way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

If you can not modify `POJO` you can implement custom serialiser or use [MixIn feature](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations).

Assume, your class looks like below:

```
class Id {
    private int oid;

    @Deprecated
    public int getOID() {
        return oid;
    }

    public int getOid() {
        return oid;
    }

    public void setOid(int oid) {
        this.oid = oid;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "oid=" + oid;
    }
}
```

You need to create an interface with extra configuration:

```
interface IdIgnoreConflictMixIn {
    @JsonIgnore
    int getOID();

    @JsonProperty
    int getOid();
}
```

Now, you need to register this interface:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.IOException;

public class JsonMixInApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Id id = new Id();
        id.setOid(1);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.addMixIn(Id.class, IdIgnoreConflictMixIn.class);

        mapper.writeValue(System.out, id);
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
{"oid":1}
```

See also:

- [Custom Jackson Serializer for a specific type in a particular class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23252918/custom-jackson-serializer-for-a-specific-type-in-a-particular-class)
- [What is equivalent code settings for @JSonIgnore annotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16939333/what-is-equivalent-code-settings-for-jsonignore-annotation)
- [Jackson parse json with unwraping root, but without ability to set @JsonRootName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568867/jackson-parse-json-with-unwraping-root-but-without-ability-to-set-jsonrootname)
- [Make Jackson serializer override specific ignored fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58763305/make-jackson-serializer-override-specific-ignored-fields)

Comment: I have a Set<Person> people which I return in Spring using ResponseEntity.ok(people). How can I use the ObjectMapper in this situation?

Comment: @Myntekt, in case of `Spring` you need to create new bean or customise already existed. Some examples how to do that you can find here: [Register a custom Jackson ObjectMapper using Spring Javaconfig](http://www.jworks.nl/2013/08/21/register-a-custom-jackson-objectmapper-using-spring-javaconfig/), [How to customise the Jackson JSON mapper in Spring Web MVC](https://magicmonster.com/kb/prg/java/spring/webmvc/jackson_custom/), [Configuring ObjectMapper in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854030/configuring-objectmapper-in-spring)